# IllegalBlockSizeException when decrypting an encrypted JSON-String after reading from a file

Tags: kotlin, encryption, cryptography, aes, javax.crypto

I'm getting an IllegalBlockSizeException after reading a previously encrypted JSON-String from a file: `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException error:1e00007b:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH`

The following code works, when I do not write the String to a file, but directly decrypt the encrypted string:

```
object Crypto {

    const val BYTEARRAY_LENGTH = 16
    const val ALGORITHM = "AES"
    const val TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"

    fun getKeyFromPassword(password: String): SecretKey {
        val keyBytes = password.toByteArray()

        if (keyBytes.size != BYTEARRAY_LENGTH) throw IllegalArgumentException("Length of password must be $BYTEARRAY_LENGTH bytes.")

        return SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, ALGORITHM)
    }

    fun encrypt(key: SecretKey, dataToEncrypt: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, IvParameterSpec(ByteArray(BYTEARRAY_LENGTH)))

        return cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt)
    }

    fun decrypt(key: SecretKey, dataToDecrypt: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, IvParameterSpec(ByteArray(BYTEARRAY_LENGTH)))

        return cipher.doFinal(dataToDecrypt)
    }
}
```

I'm reading the string with the following code and converting it to a `ByteArray` using `String.toByteArray()`:

```
private suspend fun readTextFromUri(uri: Uri): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    applicationContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
        BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use { reader ->
            var line: String? = reader.readLine()
            while (line != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line)
                line = reader.readLine()
            }
        }
    }
    return@withContext stringBuilder.toString()
}
```

This is how the file is written:

```
val encryptedExport = Crypto.encrypt(key, export.toByteArray())

try {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        applicationContext.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w")?.use {
            FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor).use { stream ->
                stream.write(encryptedExport)
            }
        }
    }
} catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    return Result.failure()
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    return Result.failure()
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the crypto API, but is the data in plain text?  And how are you writing it to the file?  I'd pay particular attention to how you're converting bytes to characters (since your `InputStreamReader` will assume the platform's default encoding when you read it back), and whether it could contain significant newlines (0x0A, 0x0D) (which will get stripped when you read it back as lines).

Comment: Please share the code that writes the ciphertext  to a file.

Comment: I added the code for file writing! @DavidSoroko

Comment: It's more efficient to store the ciphertext as binary than as string. If for some reason it should be stored as string, a suitable binary-to-text encoding like Base64 must be applied. Charset encodings like UTF8 corrupt the ciphertext. `String.toByteArray()`, for example, uses UTF8 by default and may not be used.

Comment: @user9014097 I'm generating a JSON-String, that should be encrypted. What should I use instead of ˋString.toByteArray()ˋ to convert the JSON-String to a ByteArray that is needed for encryption?

Comment: My previous comment refers to the ciphertext, not the plaintext. If the plaintext is a JSON string, it should be UTF 8 encodable (so that `String.toByteArray()` is applicable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are writing out a binary file, but reading it in as a text.

How about reading the file with code similar to:

```kotlin
fun readEncrypted(file: String): ByteArray =
    FileInputStream(file).use { it.readAllBytes() }
```

Once you decrypt the `ByteArray` you read from the file, you can convert the resulting `ByteArray` to a `String`.